# SQL Server Date when member turns 65

Tags: sql-server

I need to find the date of a member who is gonna turn 65 or 19.
I have the DOB and age.

Need a Date which shows when they will **turn 19 or 65.**

```
  Id    DOB        Age   Date_Turning_65_or_19
  --------------------------------------------
  2   1952-09-30   64       2017-09-30
```

I need that last column as a result

Please help me doing it.

I am trying different formulas but its not working.

I tried something like this

```
CASE 
   WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) <= MONTH(DateOfBirth) 
          AND DATEDIFF(YEAR, DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) = '65'
      THEN CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), MONTH( DateOfBirth)) + '/' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DAY(DateOfBirth))  + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YEAR(GETDATE())))
   WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, '19510901', GETDATE()) = '64'
      THEN CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), MONTH( DateOfBirth))  + '/' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DAY(DateOfBirth)) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YEAR(GETDATE() + 365.25)))
```

Comment: wouldn't this be just: `DATEADD(YEAR,65,DateOfBirth)`?

Comment: `DATEDIFF` always returns a numerical value - why are you comparing it against a string?? `DATEDIFF(YEAR, '19510901', GETDATE()) = '64'` - this should really read `DATEDIFF(YEAR, '19510901', GETDATE()) = 64` (**no** single quotes!)

Comment: My actual requirement is when you pass a parameter(that says I need people who are turning 65) I need those people with the date

Answer (score 2):

```
select *, 
       case when dateadd(year, 19, dob) < getdate()
            then dateadd(year, 19, dob) 
            else dateadd(year, 65, dob) 
       end
from your_table
```